# Dealing with a huge GeoJson in leaflet

Tags: javascript, optimization, leaflet, geojson

I'm currently dealing with a Huge GeoJson (about 100Mb) that contains all nation subdivisions in the world.

I want to display this GeoJson in a Leaflet map.

I have implemented [this](https://github.com/iamtekson/leaflet-geojson-vt) add-on that binds geojson-vt with leaflet.

However, simply I can't send 100Mb of data all the times...

This is a Javascript sample of the Leaflet implementation in JS:

```js
//Map init
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 1);
//Tile layer
var tile_layer = L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);
//GeoJson fetch
world_geojson = fetch('./world.json').then(response => response.json()).then(
    world_geojson => {
        var options = {
            maxZoom: 16,
            tolerance: 3,
            debug: 0,
            style: {color:'#000',fillColor:"#0f0",weight: 1,opacity: 0.5,fillOpacity: 0.2}
        };
        //Actual geojson-vt layer implementation
        var geojson_layer = L.geoJson.vt(world_geojson, options).addTo(map);
    }
);
```

There is a way or some tricks to reduce the quantity of data sent to the users?

Thanks for support!

Comment: please provide [mcve] in the OP

Comment: Split the data in tiles, beforehand, and serve those tiles.